# AWS STS Assume Role - InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, aws-config

I am trying to assume an `IAM` role using `aws-sdk` as so...

```
var sts = new AWS.STS();
sts.assumeRole({
  RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:root',
  RoleSessionName: 'awssdk'
}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) { // an error occurred
    console.log('Cannot assume role');
    console.log(err, err.stack);
  } 
  else { // successful response
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
      sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken
    });
  }
});
```

But I keep getting...

> InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid

However, I can connect if I just use the following...

```
AWS.config.update({ accessKeyId: process.env.ID, secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET });
```

Any reason why I cannot assume a role?

Comment: Hello, did you found a solution? i have completly the same problem. i try to asume a role from a lambda function (to simulate it locally). 
=> in my case it's an iam role, not a root....

Comment: Same here, did you found a solution? The arn I'm using have the right format and it is a valid Role arn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following

```
RoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:root',
```

is not the IAM role. It seems you are trying to assume the IAM root user. The correct ARN of a role has [form](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_identifiers.html#identifiers-arns) of

```
arn:aws:iam::account-id:role/role-name-with-path
```

Comment: i have an IAM Role. (Role which is also used in a lambda function). i try to asumeRole to simulate the lambda locally (incl. the role permissions). but i get an 

InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid

too.

Comment: @StefanVolkmer You could make new question about it, with the relevant details.